# How to get a page slug in the app directory of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Next.js 12, we got the slug of the current page by doing as below in a `getStaticProps`. How can this be done in Next.js 13?

**✅Next.js 12**

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const slug = context.params.slug
}
```

**❌Next.js 13** -
In Next.js13, using the above code gives this error

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
```

```
export async function fetchData(context) {
    ❌const slug = context.params.slug
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the `app` directory, your `default` exported component, located in a `page.js`, gets passed a parameter that would look like this:

```js
{ params: {...}, searchParams: {...} }
```

If you have a `slug`, it would be in `params`. But it's your page component that should pass it to your data fetching function, as an example like so:

```js
async function fetchData(context) {
    const slug = context.params.slug
}

export default async function Page(context) {
  const data = await fetchData(context)
  return <h1>My Page</h1>;
}
```